# how to add Old data to select inputs (looping by vue.js) in form

Tags: laravel, vue.js

this code is working for normal select inputs

```
            <select id="condition" name="condition"  class="@error('condition') is-invalid @enderror form-control" >
            <option value="" >Select Condition</option>
            <option value="Brand New" {{ old('condition') === 'Brand New' ? 'selected' : '' }} >Brand New</option>
            <option value="Recondition" {{ old('condition') === 'Recondition' ? 'selected' : '' }} >Recondition</option>
            <option value="Used" {{ old('condition') === 'Used' ? 'selected' : '' }} >Used</option>
            </select>
```

but I need to use old data to select inputs looping via Vue.js

```
<select class="form-control" name="model" id="model" v-model="model">
  <option v-for="option in model_options[make]" v-bind:value="option.id" v-bind:key="option.id">@{{option.text}}</option>
                                </select>
```

Comment: you probably want to create a simple `form` object in your vue component, and have that prefilled with passed in values in the `mounted()` function. Then you bind your components to properties within that object like `v-model="form.user_id"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand what you're looking for.

I think you just need to set the `model` (for `v-model="model"`) to the id of the option that you want selected.

I've included a snippet below where it does this on `mounted` based on the oldCondition.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      oldCondition: "Recondition",
      model: null,
      make: 0,
      model_options: [
        [{
          id: 1,
          text: "Brand New"
        }, {
          id: 2,
          text: "Recondition"
        }, {
          id: 3,
          text: "Used"
        }]
      ]
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.oldCondition)
      this.model = this.model_options[this.make].filter(x => x.text === this.oldCondition)[0].id;
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>Old Condition: {{oldCondition}}</div>
  <br />
  <select class="form-control" name="model" id="model" v-model="model">
    <option>Select Condition</option>
    <option v-for="option in model_options[make]" :value="option.id" :key="option.id">@{{option.text}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```